# How to call interface in flutter

Tags: performance, flutter, dart

I m trying to refresh other page from homepage
how to possible it,Some one Help me to refresh other page

this is my code

```
abstract class IsSilly {
  void makePeopleLaugh();
}


class _NewOrderScreenState extends State<NewOrderScreen>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<NewOrderScreen>,IsSilly


@override
  void makePeopleLaugh() {
    setState(() {
      isLoading=true;
    });
  }
```

same in other page how to refreshh.;....

Comment: So do you want to call an interface?

Comment: yes @10101010 ..

Answer (score 0):

```
private String getBase64String(Bitmap bitmap) {

    // give your image file url in mCurrentPhotoPath
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: So is this the solution to your question?